# CUDA __shfl_down_sync does not work with __match_any_sync

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, ptx, gpu-warp

Kernel *foo*'s goal is to compute the sum of values that has the same id as id[0]. I checked that the mask acquired from `__match_any_sync` correctly identifies all other threads in the warp with the same id. The if condition also works as expected; it only allows thread 0 and all other threads with the same id enter. However, the sum produced from `__shfl_down_sync` is wrong.

`vals` and `ids` are input arrays of length 32. `opt` is the output that stores the final sum. I tried with only one warp (`foo<<<1,32>>>`).

```
__global__ void foo(const float *vals, unsigned *ids, float *opt) {
    unsigned laneId = threadIdx.x & 0x1f;
    float val = vals[laneId];
    unsigned mask = __match_any_sync(__activemask(), ids[laneId]);

    if (mask & 0b1) {
        for (int i = 16; i > 0; i /= 2) {
            val += __shfl_down_sync(mask, val, i);
        }

        if (laneId == 0) {
            atomicAdd(opt, val);
        }
    }
}
```

There is also another kernel *bar* that does not have ids. It just computes the sum of all values on even indexes (basically as if the ids at all even indexes are 1 and all odd indexes are 0). This produces the correct sum.

```
__global__ void bar(const float *vals, float *opt) {
    int laneId = threadIdx.x & 0x1f;
    float val = vals[laneId];

    if (laneId % 2 == 0) {
        for (int i = 16; i >= 1; i /= 2) {
            val += __shfl_down_sync(0b0101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101, val, i);
        }

        if (laneId == 0) {
            atomicAdd(opt, val);
        }
    }
}
```

I've read the Nvidia blogs [1](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/using-cuda-warp-level-primitives/) [2](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-optimized-filtering-warp-aggregated-atomics/). I still don't understand what is wrong with foo :( My best guess is there's some warp sync issue between `__match_any_sync` and `__shfl_down_sync`. Explanation of what went wrong would be very helpful!

Environment: WIN11 CUDA-12.2 CC89

A working example showing the wrong results:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <random>

#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define STR(x) STRINGIFY(x)
#define FILE_LINE __FILE__ ":" STR(__LINE__)
#define CUDA_CHECK_THROW(x)                                                                                               \
    do {                                                                                                                  \
        cudaError_t result = x;                                                                                           \
        if (result != cudaSuccess) {                                                                                      \
            std::cout << FILE_LINE << " CUDA ERROR: " << cudaGetErrorString(result) << std::endl;              \
            exit(-1);                                                                                                     \
        }                                                                                                                 \
    } while(0);

__global__ void foo(const float *vals, unsigned *ids, float *opt) {
    unsigned laneId = threadIdx.x & 0x1f;
    float val = vals[laneId];
    unsigned mask = __match_any_sync(__activemask(), ids[laneId]);

    if (mask & 0b1) {
        for (int i = 16; i > 0; i /= 2) {
            val += __shfl_down_sync(mask, val, i);
        }

        if (laneId == 0) {
            atomicAdd(opt, val);
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist(0.0, 1.5);
    float *r, *val;
    unsigned *mask;
    CUDA_CHECK_THROW(cudaMalloc(&r, sizeof(float)))

    CUDA_CHECK_THROW(cudaMalloc(&val, sizeof(float) * 32))
    CUDA_CHECK_THROW(cudaMalloc(&mask, sizeof(unsigned) * 32))
    CUDA_CHECK_THROW(cudaMemset(r, 0, sizeof(float))
    float h_val[32];
    unsigned h_mask[32];
    float sum = 0.0f;

    for (int i = 31; i >= 0; --i) {
        float v = dist(mt);
        h_val[i] = v;

        if (i == 0 || dist(mt) >= 0.5f) {
            sum += v;
            h_mask[i] = 1;
        } else {
            h_mask[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    CUDA_CHECK_THROW(cudaMemcpy(val, h_val, 32 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice))
    CUDA_CHECK_THROW(cudaMemcpy(mask, h_mask, 32 * sizeof(unsigned), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice))

    foo<<<1, 32>>>(val, mask, r);

    float hv = 0.0f;
    CUDA_CHECK_THROW(cudaMemcpy(&hv, r, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    std::cout << "EXPECTED " << sum << " ;ACTUAL " << hv << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The host generates a 32-item array with randomly initialized floating point values. Only threads in the warp with its `id==1` should add to the sum. However, the result from the device is wrong. An example output:

```
EXPECTED: 16.1606; ACTUAL: 2.51008
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I added a code example and showcased the wrong results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of `__shfl_down_sync` is invalid. The programming guide states:

> Threads may only read data from another thread which is actively participating in the __shfl_sync() command. If the target thread is inactive, the retrieved value is undefined.

However, you attempt to shuffle data from inactive threads. For example, `__shfl_down_sync(0x55555555, val, 1)` will shuffle data from all inactive threads. The delta does not only account for threads with set bits in the mask.

A reduction for non-contiguous active threads is more complicated and can be found, for example, in the CUDA file `cuda-12.1/include/cooperative_groups/details/coalesced_scan.h`  , function `inclusive_scan_non_contiguous`.

There is a very simple solution to your problem without requiring the match function or non-contiguous reduction. Just set the input value of the reduction to 0 for all threads with different selector ids and use all threads for reduction.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <random>

#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define STR(x) STRINGIFY(x)
#define FILE_LINE __FILE__ ":" STR(__LINE__)
#define CUDA_CHECK_THROW(x)                                                                                               \
    do {                                                                                                                  \
        cudaError_t result = x;                                                                                           \
        if (result != cudaSuccess) {                                                                                      \
            std::cout << FILE_LINE << " CUDA ERROR: " << cudaGetErrorString(result) << std::endl;              \
            exit(-1);                                                                                                     \
        }                                                                                                                 \
    } while(0);

__global__ void foo(const float *vals, unsigned *ids, float *opt) {
    unsigned laneId = threadIdx.x & 0x1f;
    float val = vals[laneId];
    unsigned mask = __match_any_sync(__activemask(), ids[laneId]);

    if (mask & 0b1) {
        for (int i = 16; i > 0; i /= 2) {
            val += __shfl_down_sync(mask, val, i);
        }

        if (laneId == 0) {
            atomicAdd(opt, val);
        }
    }
}

__global__
void kernel2(const float *vals, unsigned *ids, float *opt) {
    unsigned laneId = threadIdx.x & 0x1f;
    float val = 0;
    if(ids[laneId] == ids[0]){
        val = vals[laneId];
    }
    for (int i = 16; i > 0; i /= 2) {
        val += __shfl_down_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, val, i);
    }
    if (laneId == 0) {
        atomicAdd(opt, val);
    }
}


int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist(0.0, 1.5);
    float *r, *val;
    unsigned *mask;
    CUDA_CHECK_THROW(cudaMalloc(&r, sizeof(float)))

    CUDA_CHECK_THROW(cudaMalloc(&val, sizeof(float) * 32))
    CUDA_CHECK_THROW(cudaMalloc(&mask, sizeof(unsigned) * 32))
    CUDA_CHECK_THROW(cudaMemset(r, 0, sizeof(float)))
    float h_val[32];
    unsigned h_mask[32];
    float sum = 0.0f;

    for (int i = 31; i >= 0; --i) {
        float v = dist(mt);
        h_val[i] = v;

        if (i == 0 || dist(mt) >= 0.5f) {
            sum += v;
            h_mask[i] = 1;
        } else {
            h_mask[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    CUDA_CHECK_THROW(cudaMemcpy(val, h_val, 32 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice))
    CUDA_CHECK_THROW(cudaMemcpy(mask, h_mask, 32 * sizeof(unsigned), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice))

    foo<<<1, 32>>>(val, mask, r);

    float hv = 0.0f;
    CUDA_CHECK_THROW(cudaMemcpy(&hv, r, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    std::cout << "EXPECTED " << sum << " ;ACTUAL " << hv << std::endl;

    CUDA_CHECK_THROW(cudaMemset(r, 0, sizeof(float)))
    kernel2<<<1, 32>>>(val, mask, r);

    CUDA_CHECK_THROW(cudaMemcpy(&hv, r, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    std::cout << "EXPECTED " << sum << " ;ACTUAL " << hv << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am aware that `__shfl_down_sync` reads from all threads (not only the ones in the mask, it just syncs the threads in the mask). However, can you elaborate a bit more on why the inactive threads would execute `__shfl_down_sync` at all? Shouldn't only the threads that meets the if condition actually able to execute `__shfl_down_sync`, since the if conditions only allows threads with id value 1 to enter?

Comment: Asume there are two threads , thread 0 is active, thread 1 is inactive. If only thread 0 executes __shfl_down_sync(0b01, val, 1) , then the source lane will be 0+1=1, which is the lane of an inactive thread.